# Loading XmlDocument into Webform control

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, wcf, webforms

I have created a WCF service which sends an sms by using the supplied values. This then return XML in a string variable. I have managed to get the string loaded into an XmlDocument but then when I try and load it onto a Webform control I get an error because the XmlDocument is in memory and does not have a physical path. How can I get this loaded into my webform control(WB_XMLOut). Please see my code below what I have tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LeadProcessTest.LeadProcessor;
using System.Xml;

namespace LeadProcessTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BT_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LeadProcessorClient LP = new LeadProcessorClient();

            string UName = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TB_UName.Text));
            string PWord = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TB_Pass.Text));
            string XMLIn = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TB_XMLin.Text));

            LP.Open();
            string Result = LP.Lead_Processing(UName, PWord, XMLIn);
            LP.Close();
            XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
            XML.LoadXml(Result);

            WB_XMLOut.Url = new Uri(XML);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try saving the `XmlDocument` before you set your control's url: `XML.Save("MyFile.xml")`.

Comment: This seems to work with a bit of modification. I had to add the full path for the file and then specify the path as my Uri. Thanks for this however I'm a bit concerned with creating a static file. Will the file get overwritten each time and if so what happens when I have 2 instances of this running at once?

Comment: Yes, the file will get overwritten. The path you specify usually reference a location on the local system (am I right?), so I don't think you have to worry about concurrency.

Comment: Never mind ignore my stupidity lol. Thanks for your help